# Creating a program that searches if a word is repeated and how many times it is in a list,

Tags: python, list

So far I have created this:

```
    a = str(input("Word 1 = "))
    b = str(input("Word 2 = "))
    c = str(input("Word 3 = "))
    d = str(input("Word 4 = "))
    e = str(input("Word 5 = "))
    f = str(input("Word 6 = "))

words = [a, b, c, d, e, f]

def count_words(words):
    for i in words:
        wordscount = {i:words.count(i)}
        print(wordscount)

count_words(words)
```

And this is what comes out:

```
{'word': 6}
{'word': 6}
{'word': 6}
{'word': 6}
{'word': 6}
{'word': 6}
```

And my question is how can I make it so it doesn't print the key in the list if it already has so for example not the above but this:

```
{'word': 6}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should slice the array and check if the word you're going to print hasn't already been checked.

```
def count_words(words):
    for index, i in enumerate(words):
        wordscount = {i:words.count(i)}
        if i not in words[0:index]:
            print(wordscount)
```

See also that I used `enumerate()` to keep track of the index inside your loop.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to Stack Overflow!

A solution to your problem would involve initialising another list, probably called `words_mentioned` above your loop, and adding to it the words that you've already printed. If the word is in `words_mentioned`, don't print it. Final code would look like this:

```
a = str(input("Word 1 = "))
b = str(input("Word 2 = "))
c = str(input("Word 3 = "))
d = str(input("Word 4 = "))
e = str(input("Word 5 = "))
f = str(input("Word 6 = "))

words = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
words_mentioned = []

def count_words(words):
    for i in words:
        wordscount = {i:words.count(i)}
        if i not in words_mentioned:
            print(wordscount)
            words_mentioned.append(i)

count_words(words)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I am a beginner and still learning and I really appreciate the answer

Comment: I'd really appreciate it if you could mark my answer as correct by clicking the grey tick mark next to my answer. It really does help!

Answer (score 0):

In order to not count words more than once, you could use a set in your `for i in words:` loop:  replace it with `for i in set(words):`

You could also use the Counter() class from iterTools:

```
from itertools import Counter
print( Counter(words) )
```